# Can Toggles be used instead of Checkboxes?

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline, style-guide

I have seen multiple applications going for safe usage of checkboxes while there is a multi-select scenario of options shown in list or under one category.

What is the rationale of having checkboxes while toggles can also do the same work. Can we use toggles instead of checkboxes?

Comment: A lot of good points in the answer above. Check out NN/g's article on this topic for additional information.
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/toggle-switch-guidelines/

Answer (score 4):

Let us look at the definition of the

In my opinion

> A **checkbox** control has three states: unselected, selected, and
> indeterminate. The last state represents a situation where a list of
> sub-options is grouped under a parent option and sub-options are in
> both selected and unselected states.

and

> The **toggle** represents a physical switch that allows users to
> turn things on or off, like a light switch.

Below are few use-cases along with guidelines to decide between these two controls while designing form experience.

**Case 1**: Instant response
Use Toggle switch when,

- An instant response of applied settings is required without an
  explicit action.
- A setting requires an on/off or show/hide function to display the
  results.
- User needs to perform instantaneous actions that do not need a review
  or confirmation.

**Case 2**: Settings confirmation
Use Checkbox when,

- Applied settings need to be confirmed and reviewed by user before
  they are submitted.
- Defined settings require an action like Submit, OK, Next, Apply
  before displaying results.
- User has to perform additional steps for changes to become effective.

**Case 3**: Multiple choices

- Multiple options are available and user has to select one or more
  options from them.
- Clicking multiple toggle switches one by one and waiting to see
  results after each click takes extra time.

**Case 4**: Indeterminate state
Use Checkbox when,

- An intermediate selection state is required when multiple sub-options
  are grouped under a parent option. The intermediate state will
  represent that multiple sub-options (but not all of them) are
  selected in the list.

**Case 5**: Clear visual state
Use Checkbox when,

- There is a chance of getting confused with on/off state of a toggle
  switch. Sometimes it gets difficult to understand whether the switch
  is showing state or action.
- A clear selected or unselected state needs to provide.

**Case 6**: Related items
Use Checkbox when,

- User has to select option(s) from a list of related items.

**Case 7**: Single option
Use Checkbox when,
A single binary yes/no choice is provided.
Only one option can be selected or deselected and its meaning is obvious.